# Can you determine the degree off your are from 90 using the pythagorean theorem?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that if $a^2+b^2=c^2$ is true then the angle of the hypotenuse to the adjacent leg is 45° and the adjacent leg to the opposite leg is 90°. However, I am wondering if you can determine the degree off of 45° using a case of $a^2+b^2 \neq c^2$. Say there is a difference of 40 between the sides of the equation, can you translate that to a degree.

Comment: this seems relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: No its not true, what you have written above means that both height and base of a right angled triangle is always equal which is not true.

Comment: What you said is not true. $a^2+b^2=c^2$ does imply that the triangle is right-angled (the right angle is opposite to the side $c$) but it doesn't imply anything about its other angles. However, for every triangle, the angle $\gamma$ opposite to $c$ satisfies (the "cosine theorem"): $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\gamma$.